# When valuing a vanilla option on an index, should we take dividend into account?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, index, dividends

When valuing a vanilla option on an index (eg FTSE 100), should we take index dividend yield into account?

$$
c=Se^{-q\tau}N\left(d_1\right)-Ke^{-r\tau}N\left(d_2\right)
$$
$$
d_1=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S}{K}\right)+\left(r-q+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}
$$
$$
d_2=d_1-\sigma\sqrt{\tau}
$$

Using the above formulae, should $q$ be 0 or "equivalent index dividend yield" when $S$ is an index (eg FTSE 100)?

Comment: The black-Scholes equation is not an sacred oracle, it is simply an approximated equation.  Then, first make the computation with q = 0; after this make the computation with q = dividend yield.  Finally compare the two results and you will obtain a variation interval for the price of the vanilla option.

Comment: Use of Black Scholes is with forward and zero-coupon bond

$$c = B(0,\tau) \left(F_{0,\tau}N(d_1)-KN(d_2)\right)$$
$$d_1 = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{F_{0,\tau}}{L}\right)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$$
$$d_2 = d_1-\sigma\sqrt{\tau}$$

Answer (score 1):

Ftse100 would not have a smooth dividend yield, as your formula has, it would be discrete, being much higher on certain days of year than others.  In pricing options on ftse, u need to take into account implied dividends (dividends that are implied by put call parity)

Answer (score 1):

When valuing a plain index option, there are two options in terms of index dividend:

(1) The underlying price is a spot price like in the FTSE 100 case (option is valued off the index): you can use continuous dividend yield. You can imply a dividend yield from a linearized call-put parity:

The present value of the dividend payment is

$PV(div)=P-C+(S-K)+K(e^{rt} - 1)$,

then the implied dividend yield is $d = \frac {PV(div)}{T*S}$

(2) The underlying instrument is a future contract on the index (for example, IBEX35 or TAIEX), you'd set index dividend yield to **zero** and use future price of corresponding maturity as an underlying price.

For the purposes of calculating option prices or implied volatilities, the use of a dividend forecasting model based on projected actual dividend growth rates can lead to an option model which is internally inconsistent. In contrast, the
use of a model based on constant dividend yields is not only consistent, but also easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Randor's answer, the standard Black-Scholes formula as you've given it assumes a constant continuous dividend yield of $q$. To adapt this to cope with discrete deterministic (absolute) dividends $d_i$ at known times $\tau_i$, you could recast the formula in terms of the "dividend-free" stock price:

$$S^* := S - \sum_i d_i e^{-r\tau_i}$$

and set $q$ to zero.

N.B. You only include dividends between spot and the option expiry.